# Connecting to iSCSI Target

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi

I've installed Microsoft iSCSI Software Target 3.3 on a server 2008 R2 machine and created a new iSCSI Target.
In the target I created a new Virtual Disk.

From another server I started iSCSI Initiator and in Targets | Target I typed the IP of the Target. (Also tried DNS name.)
But when I click Refresh I never see the target. Through googling I found [this Youtube tut](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9xML_dM1w8) from a French guy doing pretty much what I did (only difference is I'm in a domain).

I first though that maybe Port 3260 was closed but its not I can telnet to it. Also disabled all firewalls to see if that was blocking anything... No luck so far.

Does anybody know of possible reasons why I can't connect to the iSCSI Target?

If I can provide more info please let me know what's needed?
Extra info:
I've used [this tut](http://tsells.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/how-to-create-a-virtual-iscsi-san-disk-with-vmware-workstation-and-server-2008-r2/) to set things up.

Comment: perhaps you've already seen these instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338480(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: Hi uSlackr yes I've read those too but while googling some more I found the root-cause of my problem. I've fat fingerd my IQN of the Initiator. Thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While googling about connection problems I notices this [Article](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/storage/installed-microsoft-iscsi-target-clients-connect-ive-created-iscsi-targets-installation-whats-wrong-139654)

> When you create an iSCSI Target with the Microsoft iSCSI Target
>   software, you create devices and assign them to an iSCSI Target.
>
> The problem is that you need to tell the target which clients are
>   allowed to connect—which by default is no one. Select the properties
>   of the iSCSI target and, under the iSCSI Initiators tab, click Add and
>   select the IQNs of the clients who are allowed to connect. The IQNs of
>   clients that have tried to connect in the past will be displayed, or
>   you can manually type the IQN of the allowed clients. The clients
>   should now be able to connect.
>
> If you're unsure of the IQN of an iSCSI Initiator (the client), launch
>   the iSCSI Initiator Administrator Tool application on the client.
>   Under the Configuration tab, its IQN is shown.

And it explained that the iSCSI initiators tab on the Target should be correct. So I checked my IQN again and yep I fat fingered it! After entering the correct address connection was a fact!

Comment: As it says in the article Joost linked to, you have to add the iSCSI initiator on the iSCSI target, so the initiator is allowed to connect.